# Is there a MediaWiki login page CSS file?

Tags: css, mediawiki

I've changed my MediaWiki Common.css and Print.css and all modifications loaded just fine.

The problem is that all the customizations made in the Common.css are not applying in the Login page at all.

Is there a specific css file for the login page? Can anyone help me?

Comment: [mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CSS#Styles_not_working_on_Special:UserLogin_or_Special:Preferences?) just a google away 

Answer (score 1):

I found it!
All I had to do is add the following parameter to LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgAllowSiteCSSOnRestrictedPages = true;
```